# what does ruby symbol -> do?

Tags: ruby, haml

```
options_from_collection_for_select(['all'], 'to_s',  -> (input) { t("admin.mystring") })
```

I found this line of code in a Haml file. Could someone please explain what does `->(input)` do? And when to use this symbol `->` in ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what does ->(input) do?

`->() { .. }` is called staby proc.

> And when to use this symbol -> in ruby?

When you want to use a `Proc` object using [`Kernel#lambda`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) method. `->() { .. }` is a syntactic sugar of `Kernel#lambda`.

Ruby **1.9.1** introduces this new, more concise syntax for creating lambda methods.

The [stab operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/newinruby191/qt/LambdaOperator.htm) is named for its resemblance to a knife or stabbing motion: `->`. Following the stab portion of the operator, there is a argument list, just as with in a normal method. Then, a normal Ruby block in braces.

Since the lambda's argument list is a formal argument list, as opposed to a block argument list, several other features such as default argument values are supported. A *lambda* is somewhere in between an anonymous block or closure and a formal named method.

Comment: Also known as "stabby lambdas" for Google purposes.

Comment: @tadman should I rewrite `staby proc` as you suggested.

Comment: There's several terms for it, but that's one of them. It also helps people find this answer by having it here.

Answer (score 3):

The `->` operator is a shortcut for the `lambda` keyword. You can read all about them here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html